# checking if function already executed?

Tags: android, function, flags

How to check that whether a particular function has been executed before or its first time its being executed.

I know using global boolean flag in an activity can help.But want to know what is proper and efficient way to implement it.

Comment: Is your method static or non-static? Do you want to know whether the method has been called ever? Or has been called on a particular object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `SharedPreferences` for that, ,for e.g

add a `key` to your `SharedPreferences` object and initialize with value `0`.

Now before your function call check for this `key` value in `SharedPreferences`. If its value is `0` then its "First Call" and if so increment key's value by `1` so next time it will not be "FirstCall".

Hope you understood by this.

Comment: good that helped , as a side note you can do the same to check application's first run too ... :)

Answer (score 0):

Using `Log.d("DEBUG", "Function is running")` inside your function would be the most recommended way.